# Coming from @vue-cli, how to represent the project in a "simple" three-file setup ala Codepen?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, codepen

I have a @vue-cli generated project that I need to port over to a simple "three file" setup (ie only index.html, index.js, and index.css) so I can showcase portions of it on Codepen.

However, I'm having a hard time disentangling the "cli" structure of the app. The main issue seems to be two-fold:

1. CLI is wired to use single-file components whereas Codepen expects everything to be included "in-line" within the `js` file
2. Webpack is working its magic in the background to compile everything together based on CLI's single-file component structure, etc.

For example, within the `main.js` file, a CLI app imports various Vue related modules, then initializes the Vue instance with

```
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

This, of course, corresponds with the content of the `index.html`

```
...
<div id="app"></div>
```

Right now I'm manually copying and pasting things over into Codepen, but that dev environment is just atrocious for any type of serious editing and manipulation... So that's why I'd like to build it out and test stuff ***OUTSIDE*** of Codepen, then paste it all in once I'm happy with the results.

I've tried pulling all of the component code into `main.js` using the standard `Vue.component('<name>', { <options> })` syntax, but it's not playing well...

Any ideas? Thanks for the help, sorry for such a broad question!

PS: OR! Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way. Rather than try to "de-CLI" a CLI app structure, how could I create a simple "three-file" Vue app with the comforts of things like `npm run serve` with hot-loading to see things in action on the page?

Comment: Perhaps what you’re looking for is something [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/index2) can offer?

Comment: Yes, CodeSandbox is great! Unfortunately, for whatever reason, Codepen is a *must* on the receiving end. Thanks again for suggesting it!